# Hide Ribbon Button only from Outlook

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I create a custom Ribbon Button for Dynamics CRM but my wish is to hide it only from Outlook (for all users).

Our clients are using Dynamics 2011, Dynamics 2013 and Dynamics 2015.

I am new in this technology, please help me to do it. How and where?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a `<CrmClientTypeRule>`, MSDN link for reference -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328071.aspx

```
<CrmClientTypeRule
 Default=["0" | "1" | "true" | "false"]
 InvertResult=["0" | "1" | "true" | "false"]
 Type=["Web" | "Outlook"]
 />
```